# Single sourcing package dependencies with conda build, develop and pip

Tags: python, pip, conda, setuptools, conda-build

I am writing a Python package, for which I provide packaging via setuptools as well as a recipe for conda build. This allows the package to be installed via `pip` and `conda`.
Additionally, I want to provide an easy way to setup a conda environment for development, so I provide an `environment.yml` and use conda develop.
Unfortunately, this means that I have multiple files in my repository which list dependencies for my package:

- `meta.yml` Contains the build and run dependencies when packaging with conda build.
- `setup.cfg` Contains the run dependencies when packaging with setuptools.
- `pyproject.toml` Contains the build dependencies when packaging with setuptools.
- `environment.yml` Contains the build and run dependencies for development (and building the documentation).

I have no problems with splitting up the dependencies in multiple files.
However, with this setup, I need to specify many of the same dependencies at different places, which I want to avoid:

- The run dependencies need to be specified in `meta.yml`, `setup.cfg` and `environment.yml`.
- Some build dependencies need to be specified in `meta.yml`, `pyproject.toml` and `environment.yml`, while a few are specific to the packaging system and only need to be specified at one place.

Is there a way for me to single-source my dependencies or at least reduce the amount of duplication I currently have?

Comment: Split dependencies into 3 lists — common, build-only and runtime-only. Write a script to generate `environment.yml`, `meta.yml`, `pyproject.toml` and `setup.cfg` from these 3 sources.

Comment: That's definitely an option. I was however hoping that there would be some existing tools or some elegant options in conda or setuptools which cover my use-case. It seems to me that this should be a common problem.

Comment: I doubt it's a common problem. How many people use `conda build`, `conda install`, `python -m build`/`pip wheel` and `pip install` at the same time?

Comment: People who want to distribute their package for both pip and conda?

Comment: I think only a few big teams do this.

Comment: “*People who want to distribute their package for both pip and conda?*” - Conda Forge recipes prefer to track downstream of PyPI. Most developers only need to get to their packages that far; recipes for relaying onto Conda Forge are managed independently and directly on Conda Forge.